# Extending struct cdev

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a Linux device driver for a device which, from an OOP perspective, feels like a subclass (or extension) of `struct cdev`.  Such devices have to contain `struct cdev`, because otherwise it would be impossible to retrieve device data with `container_of()` when opening the /dev file:

```
struct mycdev {
   struct cdev cdev;       // We want to extend struct cdev
   u32 data[10];           // Device data
};
...
static int mycdev_open(struct inode *ip, struct file *fp)
{
   struct mycdev *dev = container_of(ip->i_cdev, struct mycdev, cdev);
   ...
}
```

What would be a safe way to release the extended `struct mycdev`?  One I can think of is overriding the default `release()` for char devices:

```
...
struct mycdev *mycdev = kmalloc(sizeof(*mycdev), GFP_KERNEL);
cdev_init(&mycdev->cdev, &mycdev_fops);
mycdev->cdev.kobj.ktype->release = mycdev_release;
...
```

Because the original `release()` is static, I have to duplicate its code by copying and pasting it in my method.  Alternatively, I could save the original method somewhere inside my device struct and then remember to call it from my method.  Is there a nicer way to do this?  For example, in `struct device` there's a `release()` that can be overidden by your hook method.

In LDD3 book examples they seem to be remiss as they allocate a slab of memory for the extended devices, then, when module unloads, they `cdev_del()` and `kfree()` the whole slab.  If somewhere in the system someone was still holding a pointer to the cdev (say a `struct inode` of an opened file), this would be horribly wrong.

Comment: How do you allocate and register your device? Unregistering should work similarly.

Comment: I use `cdev_add()` to register, `cdev_del()` to undo.  But isn't unregistering just taking the device out of the hierarchy so that it is not visible to the system? This is not equivalent to releasing it.

Comment: Where do you allocate `struct mycdev`?

Comment: Well, I `kmalloc()` a number of `struct mycdev`s at module load time. (I've edited the post to show this)

Comment: Then you deallocate it at module unload time.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I figured that this works because every `struct cdev` has an owner (e.g. my module) and then every `cdev_get()` / `cdev_put()` also affects owner's ref count.  The `delete_module()` system call waits for module ref count to be 0, and only then calls its `exit()`.